# More than one persistent service instance

Tags: angular

In my Angular app, I have two components, `Recordings` and `Participants`, which share a common sub component, `RecordingList`.

I want each of the two components to have a separate instance of the recording list. These instances should also be persistent in the sense that, when the user has visited another part of the app and returns, the lists are still present. So what I need is two instances of the recording list data structure.

There's the problem:

If I provide the `RecordingListService` that contains that data structure on the global level, it will be persistent, but there will be only one instance. If I provide it at the module level, there will be an instance every time a component is created, which happens quite frequently. What I need is a way to tell the `RecordingList` component to access one of the two needed instances, depending on whether it is contained in the `Recordings` or the `Participants` component.

Comment: Kindly enable us to help you by sharing some code

Answer (score 2):

you can provide the service by 3 ways:
in the `@Injectable` like

```
@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root',
})
```

and will be avaliable for every component because is setted on the root level.
second way;

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
  BackendService,
  Logger
 ],
 ...
})
```

this the service will be avaliable only for that ngModule(you have just one so its okey)
and 3th way:

```
@Component({
  selector:    'app-hero-list',
  templateUrl: './hero-list.component.html',
  providers:  [ HeroService ]
})
```

i think if you provide it at component level(the shared subcomponent, should work)

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the service in the component.

For example:

```
@Component({
  selector:    'app-recordings',
  templateUrl: './recordings.component.html',
  providers:  [ RecordingList ]
})
```

See documentation here:
https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#providing-services-in-component

Comment: The problem is: When the user leaves that view, e.g. to view a detail of a list entry, and returns, the component is instantiated again, and a new service instance is created. So the data stored originally are lost.

Comment: services are singletons by default, so they are instantiated only once during the lifecycle of the application.

Comment: @GérômeGrignon not true. Look at the attached link in answer

Comment: Not true in your example, but true by default (and for this purpose): https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but for the modest need I find that router strategy solution too heavyweight and too intransparent. The workaround I'm using is defining a class inheriting from my original service, and using this by the other component.